# Biopython error in first stages

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

So I am trying to use BioPython. To set it up, I've done:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

fasta_string = open("myseq.fa").read()
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta_string)
```

This returns the error

```
fasta_string = open("myseq.fa").read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myseq.fa'
```

Does this mean that it was not installed correctly, or is myseq.fa a standalone file? I've already tried reinstalling.

Comment: myseq.fa is indeed a standalone fasta file that you would provide yourself.

Comment: @Y.Luo Thank you, but since I am very new to biopython I wouldn't know how to make one.

Comment: You can start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format). Of course you would have to have something you want to test in mind first...

Answer (score 0):

myseq.fa:

```
> test-seq
ATGATGATGGGCGTAGCATT
```

put it in same directory of your script

[fasta format description from NCBI](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp)